# Dictionary in shell script only showing last associated item

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, dictionary

I am trying to use dictionaries and stumbled across a weird behavior. When I create a dictionary like this:

```bsh
declare -A servers
servers=( ["omega"]="dev" ["delta"]="test" ["beta"]="ppd" ["alpha"]="prd" )


echo "${servers["omega"]}"
```

The last element "prd" will be printed to the screen, not the first one. Deleting every entry except the first one will result in the correct output. I am not sure what I am doing wrong because every code example I had a look at is using dictionaries like above. Can anyone spot my mistake?

Greetings

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: Im running it from bash using sh binary with root privs

Comment: Does this also happen, when you enter the commands directly in the bash?
What version of bash are you using? What is the output of the following commands: echo "${!servers[@]}" echo "${servers[@]}"

Comment: It behaves as if `servers` was an array instead of associative array. Check for typos, and check that the bash version is at least 4.0 (the first one to support associative arrays).

Comment: Are you using sh or bash?

Comment: What is the version of bash you use (it behaves like if you use a version of bash prior to 4)?

Answer (score 1):

I think @Yurko's comment is the right track.

With bash prior to version 4 (such as `/bin/bash` on a Mac):

1. the `declare -A` line will emit an error (`declare: -A: invalid option`) and the array is **not declared**.
2. the 2nd line will create an *indexed* array: since the index is evaluated as an arithmetic expression
3. in bash arithmetic expressions: "bare" words are treated as the names of variables; and unset variables are given the value zero

Therefore, each string is assigned to the index `0`.

Try this:

```bsh
declare -p servers
```

and you should see the output

```bsh
declare -a servers='([0]="prd")'
```